# convert one column of many rows into many columns

Tags: r

I've a two columns in a file, like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 |
| Bat | 2 |
| Cat | 4 |
| Bat | 2.5 |
| Apple | 6 |
| Cat | 4.8 |

I want to covert Column A values into individual columns & corresponding values from Column B

| **Apple** | **Bat** | **Cat** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 2.5 | 4.8 |

Answer (score 1):

For your data, we could do it this way:

Most important is to create groups with n (in this case 3), we do it with the first row using gl() function, then we use pivot_wider:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(col2 =as.integer(gl(n(),3,n()))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ColumnA, values_from=ColumnB) %>% 
  select(-col2)
```

```
  Apple   Bat   Cat
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2   2     4  
2     6   2.5   4.8
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfourtnately I've more than 3, i.e 44 and i got this error `Error in `n()`:`
`! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.`

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have more than 3, this should work for any amount in column A

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)



 df <-
  data.frame(
    ColA = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "D", "E","D","E"),
    ColB = c(2, 2, 4, 2.5, 6, 4.8, 6, 2,3,2)
  )

 df %>% dplyr::group_by(ColA) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = ColA, values_from = ColB) %>%
  dplyr::select(-row)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
      A     B     C     D     E
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2   2     4       6     2
2     6   2.5   4.8     3     2
```

Comment: Thank you! But it resulted in the same error!! `Error in n(): ! Must be used inside dplyr verbs`

Comment: What about if you try now with the edit? I would also restart R and load dplyr again

Answer (score 1):

Using `unstack` in `base R`

```
unstack(df1, ColumnB~ ColumnA)
  Apple Bat Cat
1     2 2.0 4.0
2     6 2.5 4.8
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColumnA = c("Apple", "Bat", "Cat", "Bat", "Apple", 
"Cat"), ColumnB = c(2, 2, 4, 2.5, 6, 4.8)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```